# Merge Sort implementation with generators and recursion

Tags: python, mergesort

Just beating the dead merge-sort horse, this time with generators and recursion!

What do you think?

p.s. Not entirely sure why stack overflow needs me to post more details on a code review. I'm implementing something straight from an undergrad CS class but because it does, here Is the video that inspired me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzeBrDU-JaY

```
k=[1,2,1,3,4,2]
def merge_sort(lis):
    """this performs merge sort assuming
none of the values in lis are greater than 10**100"""
    if len(lis)<=1:
        return lis
    else:
        over=int(len(lis)/2)
        RL=lis_generator(merge_sort(lis[over:]))
        LL=lis_generator(merge_sort(lis[:over]))
        new_l=list()
        cRL=next(RL)
        cLL=next(LL)
        while len(new_l)<len(lis):
            if cRL<=cLL:
                new_l.append(cRL)
                cRL=next(RL)
            else:
                new_l.append(cLL)
                cLL=next(LL)

        return new_l

def lis_generator(lis):
    """enumerate --> index, value"""
    for i in lis:
        yield i
    yield 10**100
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually get benefits from using generators in this particular implementation since you are still slicing actual lists *having the slices created in memory*. And, you also collect the results into a `new_l` list being created in memory and returned all at once.

You should use iterative [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) like demonstrated in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515559/771848). Also, check out this [generator-based merge sort implementation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/python/mergesort-generators.py) - note how the results are yielded from the "merge sort" function.

---

Some code style related notes:

- since you return from the function when `len(lis) <= 1`, you can omit the `else:` part and decrease the indentation level of the case when `len(lis)` is more than 1
- improve your variable naming - `lis` is not a good way to workaround not naming a variable `list`, `over` should probably be `middle`, `cRL` and `cLL` should probably become `left` and `right` etc.
- documentation strings should start with a capital letter and end with a dot, according to `PEP8` style guide ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings))
- watch for other `PEP8` code style violations - specifically, watch for spaces around operators ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements))